# String Replace in several combinations

Tags: c++, .net, regex, string, replace

i have a file with XY coordinates and i want to replace "empty" coordinates by the number "0".

File:

```
X123Y456
XY123
X123
Y123 
X123Y
XY123
X
Y
```

Pattern like that:

```
X\n -> X0
Y\n -> Y0
XY  -> X0Y
```

Actually i think regex would be very nice to use but i am not sure how to do it. So i used simple String::Replace so far. The complicate thing for me is that not only situation can happen, also not only one per line.

I think i should be able to do it with:

```
System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex::Replace(INPUT, PATTERN, REPLACE);
```

The input is clear for me, the pattern not completely due to the different groups:

```
(^X$) -> X0
(Y$)  -> Y0
(^XY) -> X0Y
(^XY$) -> X0Y0
```

which would give something like.

```
(^X$)|(Y$)|(^XY)
```

The replace would be afaik something like:

```
$0 -> X0
$1 -> Y0
$2 -> X0Y
```

What i did so far is simple String::Replace:

```
  void searchReplace(String^ sFile)
  {
    if(!System::IO::File::Exists(sFile))
      return;

    System::IO::StreamReader^ sr = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader(sFile);
    System::IO::StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew System::IO::StreamWriter(sFile + ".tmp");
    String^ newLine = System::Environment::NewLine;
    //System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex regex = System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex();
    String^ pattern = "(X"+newLine+")";
    String^ sLine = "";
    while((sLine = sr->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
    {
      String^ sRes = sLine->Trim()->Replace("Y"+newLine, "Y0");
      sRes = sRes->Replace("XY", "X0Y");
      sRes = sRes->Replace("X"+newLine, "X0"); 
      sw->WriteLine(sRes);
    }
    sr->Close();
    sw->Close();

    // TODO copy / delete

  }
```

didn't try this yet due to other problems, but it basically should work. But it seems not so perfect for me and regex should be better to use.

Is there any way to do it with regex or is the string replace the optimum way? And if so, how should i use the Regex::Replace correct?

Any help/tip/suggestion would be very nice.

---

**Edit Solution:**

Thanks for your help. here is the final version which is working well for me:

```
  void searchReplace(String^ sFile)
  {
    if(!System::IO::File::Exists(sFile))
      return;

    System::IO::StreamReader^ sr = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader(sFile);
    System::IO::StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew System::IO::StreamWriter(sFile + ".tmp");
    String^ sLine = "";
    while((sLine = sr->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
    {
      sw->WriteLine(Regex::Replace(sLine->Trim(), "(?<=[XY])(?=\D|$)(?!-)", "0"));
    }
    sr->Close();
    sw->Close();

    // TODO copy / delete

  }
```

Input:

```
X-123Y-456
XY-123
X123
Y123 
X123Y
XY123
X
Y
```

Output:

```
X-123Y-456
X0Y-123
X123
Y123
X123Y0
X0Y123
X0
Y0
```

**Edit 2:** 
Added Pattern for negative coordinates which i didn't mention in my description.

```
(?<=[XY])(?=\D|$)(?!-)
```

Comment: Do you really want `XY  -> X0Y` and not `XY  -> X0Y0`?

Comment: in case "XY\n" it should replace it to "X0Y0", but in case "XY123" it shouldn't. So it depends on the order of the replacement.

Comment: That should be ok for this case, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
String output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=[XY])(?=\D|$)", "0");
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<=       # look behind to see if there is:
  [XY]     #   any character of: 'X', 'Y'
)          # end of look-behind
(?=        # look ahead to see if there is:
  \D       #   non-digits (all but 0-9)
 |         #  OR
  $        #   before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)          # end of look-ahead
```

( [Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hJ3aL5/3) **|** [Working Demo](http://ideone.com/KqzGZB) )

Comment: Nice, but it also should catch "XY123" and "X123Y". From the page it seems it doesnt?! Am i wrong?

Comment: Cause in XY123 the X is an empty coordinate which i need to replace by X0. Basically you can say every coordinate (X or Y) which is not followd by a number should be replaced by X0 or Y0. Doesnt matter where the position is

Comment: that looks better, i will try it tomorrow in my code. Let you know if its working for me

Comment: it worked, needed to extend for negative coords by myself. posted my solution at the bottom of my post. thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show me an example of a negative string that should or should not be replaced, I could probably make this work better

Comment: Well, an existing coordinate which is smaller than 0. i edited the input/output. But its working with the regex ext i did.

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
(X|Y)(?!\d)
```

matches all instances of "X" or "Y" that are not followed by a digit and captures which one (X or Y) in the first capturing group.

You could use this like

```
output = System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex.Replace(input, "(X|Y)(?!\\d)", "$10");
```

Note that this expression replaces "XY" by "X0Y0", instead of "X0Y". Is this acceptable?

Comment: It should not set "X0Y0" if Y is NOT at line end. Eg. it could be "XY123" also and that would be replaced by X0Y0.

Comment: This would replace "XY123" by "X0Y123", of course. Just the string "XY" would be replaced by "X0Y0", and your examples might be interpreted that "X0Y" would be the correct output...

Comment: I think you code also would work , yes. Thanks for your help.